# Delay event handling until events have been fired

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

In C#, what's the best way to delay handling of all known events until an entity has been fully modified?
Say, for example that an entity - MyEntity - has the properties ID, Name and Description...

```
   public class MyEntity
   {
       public Int32 ID { get; set; }
       public String Name { get; set; }
       public String Description { get; set; }
   }
```

When modifying each of these properties, an event is fired for each modification.

Sometimes, the ID is the only property modified and sometimes all properties are modified. I want the registered listeners of the modification event to wait until all properties being modified in the "batch" have been modified.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

In my head, something similar to the UnitOfWork-pattern, where it is possible to wrap a using statement around the method call in the top level of the call stack but have no clue how to implement such a thing...

Edit:
As a clarification... Listeners are spread out through the application and are executing in other threads. Another actor sets - for example - the name it must call the MyEntity.Name property to set the value.

Due to the design, the modification of the Name property can trigger other properties to change, thus the need for listeners to know that the modification of properties have been completed.

Comment: Depends a lot on other requirements, e.g. do the listeners act on single property changes or do they always process the entity, regardless of the amount and location of modifications?

Comment: Why not use flags? If flag 1 and 2 are set, but 3 is not... don't do anything. When the event fires and flag 3 is set, THEN process whatever code it is that you want to execute.

Comment: OT:
I  realised that my original thought with the "using" statement originated from the log4net implementation where log4net.NDC.Push() is called to push a context message to the current thread's context...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the code performing the modifications can know when its batch of changes is complete.

What I did with my similar classes is to provide `SuspendNotifications()` and `ResumeNotifications()` methods, which are called in the obvious way (i.e. call suspend before making a bunch of changes, call resume when done).

They internally maintain a counter which is incremented in SuspendNotifications() and decremented by ResumeNotifications(), and if the decrement results in zero, a notification is issued. I did it this way because sometimes I would modify some properties and then call another method which modified some more, and which itself would call suspend/resume.

(If resume is called too many times, I thrown an exception.)

If multiple properties are changed, the final notification doesn't name the property being changed (since there is more than one). I suppose you could accumulate a list of changed properties and issue that as part of the notification, but that doesn't sound very useful.

Also note that thread safety may or may not be an issue for you. You might need to use locking and/or `Interlocked.Increment()` etc.

The other thing is that of course you end up needing try/catch around your calls to suspend/resume in case there's an exception. You can avoid that by writing a wrapper class that implements IDisposable and calls resume in its Dispose.

Code might look like this:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    try
    {
        _entity.SuspendNotifications();
        setProperties();
    }

    finally
    {
        _entity.ResumeNotifications();
    }
}

private setProperties()
{
    _entity.ID = 123454;
    _entity.Name = "Name";
    _entity.Description = "Desc";
}
```

---

[EDIT]

If you were to introduce an interface, say `ISuspendableNotifications`, you could write an `IDisposable` wrapper class to simplify things.

The example below illustrates the concept; The use of `NotificationSuspender` simplifies (in fact removes) the try/catch logic.

Note that `class Entity` of course does not actually implement suspend/resume or provide any error handling; that's left as the proverbial exercise for the reader. :)

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public interface ISuspendableNotifications
    {
        void SuspendNotifications();
        void ResumeNotifications();
    }

    public sealed class NotificationSuspender: IDisposable
    {
        public NotificationSuspender(ISuspendableNotifications suspendableNotifications)
        {
            _suspendableNotifications = suspendableNotifications;
            _suspendableNotifications.SuspendNotifications();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _suspendableNotifications.ResumeNotifications();
        }

        private readonly ISuspendableNotifications _suspendableNotifications;
    }

    public sealed class Entity: ISuspendableNotifications
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public void SuspendNotifications() {}
        public void ResumeNotifications() {}
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity();

            using (new NotificationSuspender(entity))
            {
                entity.Id = 123454;
                entity.Name = "Name";
                entity.Description = "Desc";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks kind of my initial thought of a using statement. I guess that I could add the events to an internal queue and then process the queue when notifications are resumed.

If so - I'd need something in the queue to let listeners know when a batch is complete...

Comment: A good MSDN example of this pattern is from Control with it's [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and [ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx)

Comment: This is the solutino I think I'll go for. With a counter connected to the Resume and Suspend methods, it will be possible to know when the parent using statement has been reached (hence, all modifications completed) and the events can be sent in (almost) a single shot or packaged or aggregated into a single event with children.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest

```
public class MyEntity
{
    private const int FieldsCount = 3;

    private Int32 id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    private HashSet<string> dirty = new HashSet<string>();

    public Int32 ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            dirty.Add("id");
            GoListeners();
        }
    }

    //...

    private void GoListeners()
    {
        if (dirty.Count == FieldsCount)
        {
            //...
            dirty.Clear();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be tough, as events are fired asynchronously, but are handled synchronously by the thread of execution. One possibility would be to use `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent` and use the `WaitOne`-method to wait for the `Set` to release it.
You would probably need to use it in conjuction with a `Mutex`. But if you are only working on a single thread this won't work.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) for `ManualResetEvent` and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) for `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: The application is multithreaded. Maybe the best option would be to "collect" all events in a single parent event (where the sub events are children)?

Comment: @Forest I don't know very much of the structure of your program. If you are able to combine it, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your events use the same signature:

1. Initialise a delegate  eg `eventQueue` at MyEntity instantiation, and an int value eg 'queueRequiredLength'
2. Each property setter adds adds their event to the queue if not already present, `eventQueue += newEvent;` instead of just firing off the event.
3. Each property setter then checks the length of the queue and fires the delegate (ie all the queued events) `if(length == queueRequiredLength) {eventQueue();}`

(Off top of my head I'm not sure how to check the number of methods "queued" in the delegate, but worst case you could also just keep a counter and increment that with each addition to the queue).